# Android Over the Air (OTA) installation

Tags: android, installation, ota

I have developed an android .apk file and I need to put it on my website for OTA installation (For some reasons, I cannot put it on Android Market).  The idea is, I will send sms with the link of .apk file to the android device and by clicking the application should start download and installation process.
At the moment, when I try, it is a two step process - 
1. it downloads the .apk file 
2. I need to click on .apk file to install it.

Is there anyway to remove step 2 (click on .apk file to install it) and by clicking on url of .apk file, it gets downloaded and installed (of course by asking all the necessary permission from user so it is not a security threat to user).

I have done similar thing on Blackberry/Symbian/Winmo and it is just one step process (clicking on the link downloads and runs the installer) so I thought there should be a way on android as well.
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Why can't you use an app store?

Comment: [Nishant Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067444) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68657684) saying "Yes it is possible. IF you have ROOT access. Here is a medium article on how to do it. [Over-the-air (OTA) updates for Android apps -> download apk + silent APK installation + auto launch updated app + notifying updated app about successful installation (compatible with Android 10+, needs ROOT access)](https://medium.com/@jnishu1996/over-the-air-ota-updates-for-android-apps-download-apk-silent-apk-installation-auto-launch-8ee6f342197c)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

If you already have an application running on the user's device, you could register for a special URI and download and open the file yourself. Android itself does not have such an option (for obivous reasons).

Comment: thanks Jan for reply. Somehow I cannot agree to "for obvious reasons" part. I understand why silent installation is not permitted because that could lead to security breach. But by not permitting this kind of installation where user is needed to accept/reject installation does not make sense to me.

Comment: The problem is that a website can initiate the download of any file without direct interaction of a user. If that file would be opened automatically, this would cause a lot of problems, e.g. an average user, that is suddenly confronted with an app installation dialog would maybe just click *ok*. So this is a design decision of the Android developers to improve security for the average non-technical user.